# STUCK python codecademy: a real win

Tags: python, function, break

I'm nearing the end of a lesson on creating a very simple battleship game. Basically you get 4 chances to guess the location of the ship. if you lose: game over. If you win before all 4 chances you're supposed to end the game using a "`break`" function.

Problem is: After inserting "`break`", I get an error msg reading:

```
File "python", line 33
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Here is my code, please and thank you for any help it is much appreciated:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col
turn = 1
for turn in range(4):
    print turn 
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
    break
else:
    if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
        print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
    elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
        print "You guessed that one already."
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    print turn + 1
    print_board(board)

if turn == 3:
    print "Game Over"
```

Comment: Your indentation caused the problem. The `if guess_row == ..` and `else` should be inside the `for` loop

Comment: Check your indentation. Your `break` is not part of the `for` loop.

Comment: from ```if guess_row == ship_row...``` to the end of the program (```print "Game Over"```) should be indented inside the for loop

Comment: it worked! this was helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your break is outside the loop indeed. Try to fix indentation in if-else statement on line 31 like this:

```
for turn in range(4):
...
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
      print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
      break
    else: 
...
```